# What accents 2-XL robot resembles?

Tags: american-english, accent

[2-XL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-XL) is an interactive educational toy robot that asks questions using old cassette technology!

[image: Picture from the robot]

([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:2-xltiger.JPG))

While watching clips about the toy, e.g. https://youtu.be/KpLkztVIJrc?t=35, I noticed it uses an interesting alternative pronunciation for words such as 'question', 'instruction' and 'button', all  having Ā at the ending syllable.

From what I discovered about the accent it apparently is supposed to be a New York/Brooklyn accent per [this](http://www.2xlrobot.com/types/mego.html) "his distictive New York accented voice" and [this](https://globaltoynews.com/2021/03/16/this-week-lou-ottens-cassette-tapes-and-the-2-xl-talking-robot/) "the toy featured the same distinctive Brooklyn accent as its inventor". However, when I searched about Brooklyn's accent, I weren't convinced the robot's accent is only inspired from Brooklyn's accent and thought possibly the narrator intentionally uses another accents, say French one, just to show how intellect the robot is or referring to other stereotypes I'm not aware of.

So I was wondering, can someone more confidently explain what they feel from the alternative pronunciation the robot uses?

Comment: My initial guess, before reading the final couple of paragraphs, was that it was a Japanese approximation of an American accent. I'll leave the answers to US speakers who have a better idea of what a New York/Brooklyn accent really sounds like.

Comment: As a New Yorker, I'd say that this is a bad robotic rendition (possibly involving a SSML-to-voice program of inferior quality to Microsoft Windows' TTS software) of a bad approximation of a Japanese conception of a generic New York (not specifically Brooklyn) accent.

Comment: As a US speaker, to me it  sounds mostly AmE and those particular sounds you point out just sound strange, not part of any regional accent. Most likely, since at the time of production of these kinds of games everything was done by one or two people (graphics, sound, game story, packaging, etc) that it as just the documentation producer (an American) trying to sound robotic and adding in a little quirk to sound alien.

Comment: Those particular words sound like an American trying to effect a stereotypical Asian accent.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because speech synthesis technology from almost 50 years ago can't meaningfully be analyzed in terms of [intended?] regional accents.

Comment: It's an overcaffeinated and charming blend, for sure. I hear my native Brooklyn (of the many, this one's early Streisand), robotic (Lost in Space original TV series), and clown-speak recording.

Comment: All great answers, thank you very much, @FumbleFingers why not turn one of them to an answer and just mark it as the accepted answer instead closure? Personally I didn't want to have an "exact" analysis but just more on the feeling such accent was supposed to give, pretty they've heard themselves before the publish at least so they knew their alternative pronunciation will give some feeling which is already mentioned by Yosef for example. Thanks!

Comment: @EbrahimByagowi: I think it's potentially misleading / unhelpful to "formally" associate some relatively primitive "speech engine" with a regional accent. People who don't know any better might think they could actually ***use*** the sound of a 2-XL robot's voice to help them identify some specific regional accent *in the real world*. That would obviously be a stupid thing to do, but people do do stupid things sometimes.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think even you answer can be an education and helpful one to help people not mislead, personally I wanted to suggest someone for going for such accent for a project they had (not exact mimic but just having some thought for some alternative regional pronunciations) so knowing what you said can be helpful for someone like me.

Comment: I haven't listened to any of your links, but I stand by my assertion that 50-year-old recordings (of unusual / uncertain provenance) are *not* likely to be useful to people wishing to learn English. And if anyone makes the mistake of using such sources to help them recognise / categorise *real, current* regional accents, they're more likely to be ***counterproductive*** rather than simply ***useless***.